# Debug for reading JSON file with Python Pandas

Tags: python, json, pandas

I got stuck when I was trying to simply read JSON file with `Pandas.read_json`. When I try with this sample dataset, it's great.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_json('sample.json')
```

My sample JSON file looks like below:

```
[{"field1": "King's Landing", "field2": 4, "field3": "2014-01-25", "field4": 4.7, "field5": 1.1, "field6": "2014-06-17", "field7": "iPhone", "field8": 15.4, "field9": true, "field10": 46.2, "field11": 3.67, "field12": 5.0}, {"field1": "Astapor", "field2": 0, "field3": "2014-01-29", "field4": 5.0, "field5": 1.0, "field6": "2014-05-05", "field7": "Android", "field8": 0.0, "field9": false, "field10": 50.0, "field11": 8.26, "field12": 5.0}, {"field1": "Astapor", "field2": 3, "field3": "2014-01-06", "field4": 4.3, "field5": 1.0, "field6": "2014-01-07", "field7": "iPhone", "field8": 0.0, "field9": false, "field10": 100.0, "field11": 0.77, "field12": 5.0}]
```

Unfortunately, when I just tried simply replace with file name with my full dataset, it returns the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2885, in run_code
exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-63-02c20a7d81eb>", line 1, in <module>
df1 = pd.read_json('train.json')
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/json.py", line 210, in read_json
date_unit).parse()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/json.py", line 278, in parse
self._parse_no_numpy()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/json.py", line 495, in _parse_no_numpy
loads(json, precise_float=self.precise_float), dtype=None)
  ValueError: Expected object or value
```

Anyone could help me debug why it says this?

Comment: Presumably because there is an error in the JSON file.  I'd recommend you try reducing the file bit by bit until you find the part that is causing the problem.

Comment: Try `python -c "import json; json.loads(open('train.json').read())"` in your shell.  It should indicate where the cursor in the file is when it encounters the problem.  The error is with the JSON data, not `pandas`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you have misspelled your JSON filename...

the following script gives me exactly the same error message:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_json('THERE_IS_NO_SUCH_FILE.json')
```

You may also want to validate your JSON file [here](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/)

If your JSON file is too big to be parsed online try the following:

```
python -m json.tool your_json_file.json
```

It should show you the place where the first parsing/validation error occurs

Comment: Thanks MaxU! It's really weird that I believe I'm using the correct file name while I also tested what you said and I got the same error too. Also, my actual training dataset is more than 10M, so I couldn't test it in the link. :(

Comment: @ChenLi, i've updated my answer. Did you check it with the "json.tool" - did it help?

Comment: That's really appreciated! It's a really useful tool! And there is indeed a syntax error with my file.